Can't open or create hdf5 files with h5py
I'm trying to work with hdf5 files for ml, and I keep getting this error whenever I create or open an hdf5 file. I'm using a miniconda environment in vscode on windows.
import h5py

hdf5_filepath = 'filepath'
h = h5py.File(hdf5_filepath, 'w')


OSError: [Errno 0] Unable to synchronously create file (unable to lock file, errno = 0, error message = 'No error', Win32 GetLastError() = 1)

Closest thing I got on the internet was this but didn't work:
import os os.environ["HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING"] = "FALSE"

Also tried uninstalling and reinstalling h5py package on conda but that didn't work.

When you tried setting os.environ["HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING"] = "FALSE", did you do this prior to the line with import h5py?  Have you tried setting the environment variable at the system level instead of setting it in your script at runtime?  There is a long github issue thread from other users with this issue, and it appears another possible solution would be using the locking parameter of h5py.File() such as h = h5py.File(hdf5_filepath, 'w', locking=False)

You can't put the assignment on the same line as import. Is there supposed to be a newline after import os?

First, I DON'T recommend that you disable file locking. Generally it is a symptom of another problem. The default is set to True for a reason -- to avoid file corruption when a file is opened multiple times with write access. (HDF5 default I/O access is SWMR: Single Write: Multiple Read.)
Stack Overflow has a post with multiple examples of HDF5 file locking problems. I wrote an answer that described the scenarios that can lead to this issue, and consolidated the various solutions (and when/why each is appropriate). You can read it here: Locking of HDF files using h5py. It also explains ways to avoid the error.
BTW, have you tested to be sure you can open with read access?
with h5py.File(hdf5_filepath,'r') as h5f:
   print(h5f)

If you use Python's with/as context manager, you don't have to manually close the file (or worry about abnormal exits). It will be done automatically when you exit that code block.
